# Google play console | Pre-launch report | Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-console, capacitor, ionic6

I am developing a mobile application with ionic capacitor. 4 days a go we have uploaded our first testing version to google play console,
we had 3 Crashes reports in different devices, all with the same message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: 
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }:
         app is in background uid UidRecord{b74db5c u0a192 TRNB bg:+1m35s296ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
```

we have tried to reproduce the error using emulators with exactlly what is mentioned in the report with no luck.

Below is the fulls stack we have for the error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.vending:instant_app_installer, PID: 19791
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b74db5c u0a192 TRNB bg:+1m35s296ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4035)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1924)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b74db5c u0a192 TRNB bg:+1m35s296ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1715)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1670)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:720)
    at alj.a(PG:2)
    at alm.a(PG:3)
    at wnv.a(PG:2)
    at com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver.onReceive(PG:6)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4026)
```

this is our first try to publish a mobile application, and we are not sure if this crash report is why the application is not being approved or not

[image: this is the message we got for the error]
[image]

Comment: Just saw this error today too.

Comment: We encounter the same issue. The report says only happen on Pixel 5 but physical devices work normally. This issue have been marked 'fixed' but keeps coming back once a while. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160907013